# Which Design Patterns can I use for this case?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I need to implement a upload file service, so i have a classe named `UploadService` with one method named `Upload`. I have 3 integrations 3rd party to use: `AwsS3`, `Google Storage` and `Azure Storage`, but my class service dont need to know which intergration it will use and even know how to integrate with them. I was looking to the following patterns: `Abstract Factory`, to choose and create my upload integration class in runtime and the pattern `Adapter` to create a solid contract between my `UploadService` class domain and 3rd party integrations classes. So my code looked like this:

`UploadService` class:

```
public class UploadService
{
    private IUploadAdapter _adapter;

    public UploadService(IUploadFactory factory)
    {
        _adapter = factory.Create();
    }

    public void Upload(File file)
    {
        _adapter.Upload(file);
    }
}
```

`UploadFactory` class which switch a enum UploadApi that come from environments variables:

```
public class UploadFactory : IUploadFactory
{
    private IAwsS3Adapter _awsS3Adapter;
    private IGoogleStorageAdapter _googleStorageAdapter;
    private IAzureStorageAdapter _azureStorageAdapter;

    public UploadFactory(IAwsS3Adapter awsS3Adapter, IGoogleStorageAdapter googleStorageAdapter, IAzureStorageAdapter azureStorageAdapter)
    {
        _awsS3Adapter = awsS3Adapter;
        _googleStorageAdapter = googleStorageAdapter;
        _azureStorageAdapter = azureStorageAdapter;
    }

    public IUploadAdapter Create()
    {
        switch(UploadApi)
        {
            case "AwsS3": return _awsS3Adapter;
            case "GoogleStorage": return _googleStorageAdapter;
            case "AzureStorage": return _azureStorageAdapter;
        }
    }
}
```

Each interface `IAwsS3Adapter`, `IGoogleStorageAdapter` and `IAzureStorageAdapter` implements `IUploadAdapter`.

Comment: `switch(UploadApi)` where does UploadApi come from?

Comment: Environment variables, its a enum.

Comment: So, there can ever only be one of those? Why not handle it through Dependency Injection? `services.AddSingleton<IUploadAdapter, ConcreteCloudServiceAdapter>();` Done. You can even put that in a convenience ExtensionMethod. `AddAwsUploadAdapter()`, ... Or use the Env-Var to determine which Concrete Implementation to register.

Comment: I dont have any issues to make this work, my doubt is more theoric. Named ```UploadFactory``` make sense? And all the Adapter classes still a ```Adapter``` pattern?

Comment: Sure. The factory is superfluent, though. And: this forces the DI to actually create all three instances, unless you do some magic with `Lazy`.

Comment: Great! If I need to choose a adapter in runtime and not come from env variables, how do you design and which desgin patterns would you use in this case?

Comment: Ok, that's a different story. In that case, a Factory makes more sense, probably. But there are more similiar patterns. Maybe Strategy Pattern. Depends on how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: See [Appropriate design pattern for the payment modules c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48809896) and the linked references for examples of the strategy pattern that are somewhat similar to this one.