# Strategy pattern used in Factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am writing code with the factory pattern. In switch case, I am actually returning Class objects. Using this return class, I am going to call a method. Is this an example of strategy pattern?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public interface IVehicle
    {
          void Manufacture();
    }

    public class Car : IVehicle
    {
        public void Manufacture()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Car Manufacturing");
         }
     }

     public class Bike : IVehicle
     {
         public void Manufacture()
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Bike Manufacturing");
         }
     }

     public static class factory
     {
         public static IVehicle GetVehicle(string name)
         {
            switch(name)
            {
                case "Car":
                    return new Car();
                case "Bike":
                    return new Bike();
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }
        }
    }

    public class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter Car or Bike for manufacture");
            var vehicleName = Console.ReadLine();
            factory.GetVehicle(vehicleName).Manufacture();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

}
```

Can you clear my misunderstanding here? Is this code is an example of factory and strategy pattern both?
Thank you in advance.

**EDIT**

Is this an example of Strategy pattern? I just edited Program.cs

```
public class program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter Car or Bike for manufacture");
        var vehicleName = Console.ReadLine();
        var vehicle = factory.GetVehicle(vehicleName);


    }

    public void manufacture(IVehicle vehicle)
    {
        // assume that this method is in different class and method is calling with strategy as i understood.
        vehicle.Manufacture();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be better suited to [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I don't believe this is an example of the strategy pattern, since there is no strategy interface being used. Everything is hard-coded in the factory class.

Comment: what you have implemented in here is a simple example of **Factory Pattern** and not of a **Strategy Pattern** as also stated by [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/john) in the comment above. For a better understanding have a look at [Strategy Pattern vs Factory pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/616836/2417602).

Comment: thank you @John and vikscool. 
I have edited the question if you can clear my doubt.

Comment: Even with manufacture this is not strategy pattern

Comment: @DarshitGandhi if you dont understand something with our answers feel free to ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is example of Factory Method with Parameter. You can do Factory method without parameter that is better practice.

Strategy Pattern edits alghoritm, i like do Strategy from `Abstract class`, not `Interface`.

For example, your Strategy might look like this:

First, a `Strategy` class. For example it will be calculate Fuel Consumption:

```
public abstract class Strategy
{
    public abstract int FuelConsumption(int km);
}
```

Now, you do your `strategies`. I will do two of them, for fast driving and for slow driving:

```
public class FastDriving : Strategy
{
    //you need to override abstract methods from abstract class that
    // are mentioned in Strategy as acstract, or any else abstract class
    public override double FuelComsumption(int km) => km * fuelPer100Km;

    private int fuelPer100Km = 30;
}

public class SlowDriving : Strategy
{
    //same history as above
    public override double FuelComsumption(int km) => km * fuelPer100Km - 100;

    private int fuelPer100Km = 10;
    //u need to edit alghoritm to strategy be a strategy
}
```

Now, in every Vehicle you can do a property of your `Abstract Class Strategy`:

```
public class Bike : IVehicle
 {
     public void Manufacture()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Bike Manufacturing");
     }

     int i = 1000; //some propertys needed to calculate alghoritm

     // method in vehicle class that we use to strategy, to edit our alghoritm
     public int CaluculateFuelConsumption() => Strategy.FuelConsumption() - i;

     //here is a property of your strategy
     public Strategy strategy {get; set;};
 }
```

Now, You need to populate your Strategy. You can do it in class body if you want or in main:

```
Strategy strategy = new FastDriving();
Strategy strategy = new SlowDriving();
```

But you can do it even better.

Just do an abstract class, for example `Vehicle`:

```
public abstract class Vehicle 
{
    public Strategy strategy {get; set;};
}
```

And then, your Vehicle can look like this:

```
 public class Bike : Vehicle, IVehicle
 {
      public void Manufacture()
     {
     Console.WriteLine("Bike Manufacturing");
     }

     int i = 1000; //some propertys needed to calculate alghoritm

     // method in vehicle class that we use to strategy, to edit our alghoritm
     public int CaluculateFuelConsumption() => Strategy.FuelConsumption() - i;

     //We deleted Strategy, because abstract Car class have already Strategy
     //We dont need override non abstract method. Only abstract propertys
     //need to be overrided
   }
```

Now, in your main class you can do List of Cars, Populate it by Factory Method and attach `Strategy`

```
List<Vehicle> vehicles= new List<Vehicle>();

foreach(Vehicle vehicle in vehicles)
    {
        //its not factory, but you can use factory for your post here
        switch(name)
        {
            case "Car":
                vehicle =  new Car();
            case "Bike":
                vehicle = new Bike();
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        //now, we populate strategy
        vehicle.strategy = new FastDriving():

    }
```

Then you can calculate all Fuel Consumptions by one loop:

```
 foreach(Vehicle vehicle in vehicles)       
        int fuel += vehicle.CalculateFuelConsumption();
```

Strategy, that i write is a `PUSH` Strategy. There is `PULL` Strategy too. You can read about on the net. I belive, my answer is enough for you to understand, how strategy works :)

If you want read more about patterns, i recomend you that site:

[Design Patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

Comment: Where is the factory pattern in the whole story?

Comment: Factory pattern is not a case. In first foreach he can use his switch to populate list of Cars in `new Bike()` or `new Car()`, as he wish.

Comment: Ok, i edited my answer. If it will be not enough for OP, i will do a working example from his code. I belive he wil get it, how to do it by my code above (i edited `foreach` where i populate cars with strategy)

Comment: OP need to mention, what his strategy need to do. THere is no point to using strategy when he dont have alghoritm to edit by strategy

Comment: The point is that he is learning and the example he chose and you update is not really good. I would rather propose to make `factory` which receive for example `EnviromentFriendlyComute` and `FastComute` strategy and then return bike or car respectively...

Comment: OK, in next edit i will look closely to his original post. For this state of my answer i belive he will understend strategy a little more. I provided my answer with working example of strategy too.

Comment: @michasaucer Got It. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I'd say Yes, the `GetVehicle` method is an example of a specialised factory pattern called the [simple factory](https://garywoodfine.com/simple-factory-pattern/), and you are using the thing it returns in the way that a strategy pattern would be used - the calling code is agnostic about the concrete implementation of the strategy.