# Avoid casting and instanceOf

Tags: java, design-patterns, casting, instanceof

I got an interface

```
public interface Details {
   // nothing needed until now
}
```

which is used in a class like the following:

```
public class Value {
    // many fields
    private Details details;

    public Value(SomeType type) {
        switch (type) {
        case TYPE_1:
        case TYPE_2:
            this.details = new DetailsA();
            break;
        case TYPE_3:
            this.details = new DetailsB();
            break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException("not yet implemented");
        }
    }

    public Details getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }
}
```

The interface has two implementations

```
public class DetailsA implements Details {

    private BigDecimal betragA;

    public DetailsA() {
    }

    public BigDecimal getBetragA() {
      return this.betragA;
    }

    public void setBetragA(BigDecimal betragA) {
      this.betragA = betragA;
   }

}

public class DeailsB implements Details {

    private BigDecimal betragB;
    private boolean booleanB;

    public BetragB() {
    }

    public BigDecimal getBetragB() {
        return this.betragB;
    }

    public void setBetragB(BigDecimal betragB) {
        this.betragB = betragB;
    }

    public boolean isBooleanB() {
        return this.booleanB;
    }

    public void setBooleanB(boolean booleanB) {
        this.booleanB = booleanB;
    }

    // some more fields

}
```

I got a model class in which I want to use those details, depending on the instance.

```
 public class Model extends AbstractModel {

    private Details details;

    public void init(StoerungValue stoerung) {
        setDetails(stoerung.getSchaden().getDetails());
    }

    private void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
    // ...
```

In there I have some operations like the following

```
    // ...  
    public void setBooleanB(boolean booleanB) {
        if (details instanceof DetailB) {
            ((DetailB) details).setBooleanB(booleanB);
        }
    }
    // ...
```

How can I avoid this casting and instanceOf stuff? Is any of the design patterns applicable here?

Comment: have you considered adding the isBoolean and setBoolean functions to the interface and adding them to both classes, where the implementation for class A does nothing?

Comment: You may have an abstraction problem here. 

If your operation requires to know what is the implementation of Details, it should rather work directly with the supported implementation. Else, each time you'll add a new implementation, you'll have to update your operation code, which goes against the abstraction model.

Alternatively, your operation could deal only with what's common to all Details implementations, and delegate the implementation specific processing to a dedicated method in the interface.

Comment: Interfaces with no methods are a design smell.  The entire purpose of an interface is to define an interaction protocol that an object must adhere to.  If that protocol contains no methods, then it provides nothing over just using `Object`.  Either all of your `Details` classes have a common interaction pattern, or they don't.  If they don't they're not really related, and their types should reflect that.  If they do, then the interface should define that relationship.

Comment: I edited my initial post and now you can see why I use the interface. The class 'Value' has the details encapsulated. I don't want the value to have all the different Detail-types (like getDetailsA(), getDetailsB(), ...).

Comment: "polymorphism only makes sense when the polymorphic behavior is really a behavior of the target. When it's the behavior of the observer, you need runtime typing." https://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/when-polymorphism-fails

Comment: So, what would you suggest to do in this situation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to instanceof?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721622/alternative-to-instanceof)

Comment: What do you think of the solution putting all methods of DetailsB and DetailsA into the interface? The methods that are not needed in one of the implementations throws an UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: That depends on if you think getting an `UnsupportedOperationException` is better than getting a `ClassCastException`.  I would argue that it is not better, and the dilemma here is that your `Model` class is actually dependent on a specific implementation of `Details` rather than the interface.  `Model`'s implementation *needs* a `Details` that understands (and properly answers) `setBooleanB`.

Comment: @IanMcLaird interfaces with no methods are known as _marker interfaces_ and are advocated by Effective Java Item 37. For an example, see [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Comment: Not all methodless interfaces are automatically markers (this particular case appears not to be a proper marker, since the asker is trying to access data through them), and marker interfaces could be considered an outdated technique, better expressed as metadata (annotations).  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552677/are-empty-interfaces-code-smell

Comment: @IanMcLaird, agreed. This particular question is about poor design. I simply wanted to provide a counterexample to the statement about, _"The entire purpose of an interface..."_. Effective Java specifically lists advantages of marker interfaces over annotations.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem you have here is a collection of design smells.  You've painted yourself into a corner, and there may not be an easy way out.  I don't know if this solution will work for you or not, but you can at least consider this.

The first design smell is that you have created an inheritance relationship where none actually exists.  In short, the hierarchy rooted at `Details` violates the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  When a class claims (as `Model` does) to support the `Details` interface, it's making the claim that *any* implementation of `Details` will do.  The program's correctness and behavior shouldn't change whether it's given a `DetailsA`, a `DetailsB`, or some `FooDetails` class that hasn't even been invented yet.

The reality is that `DetailsA` and `DetailsB` are not actually related.  You can see this because `Details` has no methods, and thus may as well be `Object` which any two classes already inherit from.

The second design smell is "Feature Envy."  It seems that many methods of `Model` are just pass-through calls to its underlying `details` property.  You could consider, rather than having `setBooleanB` on `Model` to just provide a `getDetails` method, and then let the caller work directly on the `Details` object.  This won't remove the `instanceof` checks or casting, but it will move them out of this class.

The third thing here is related two the first two.  `Model` depends not on `Details` as its property types would tell you, but rather on (at least) `DetailsB`.  If that's the case, then its property type should say so.  Now, it's possible that *sometimes* you need a `Model` with a `DetailsA` and *sometimes* you need a `Model` with a `DetailsB`, but it can't be both *at the same time*.  In that case, you can work around the issue with generics.

First, make the `Model` class generic, with a type parameter that tells what its underlying `Details` must actually be.

```
public abstract class Model<T extends Details> {
    private T details;

    public void init(T dets) {
        setDetails(dets);
    }

    public void setDetails(T dets) {
        this.details = dets;
    }

    public T getDetails() {
        return this.details;
    }
}
```

Then, create two subclasses that are bound to different `Details` types, and can thus promise to do the right thing without requiring casting or instanceof calls.

```
public class ModelA extends Model<DetailsA> {
    public BigDecimal getBetragA() {
        return this.getDetails().getBetragA();
    }
}

public class ModelB extends Model<DetailsB> {
    public boolean getBooleanB() {
        return this.getDetails().isBooleanB();
    }

    public void setBooleanB(boolean boolB) {
        this.getDetails().setBooleanB(boolB);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if that'll fix your problem or not, but it's something to consider.