# What causes "incompatible conditional operand" when using instanceof in Java?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, instanceof

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [instanceof - incompatible conditional operand types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551337/instanceof-incompatible-conditional-operand-types)

I am trying to use below code and getting compilation error.

```
Class<A> clas; //this is passed from service 
clas instanceof SomeClass
```

This gives ma the following compilation error:

> incompatible conditional operand types Class and SomeClass

Please help me!

Comment: Please post some actual code that demonstrates the problem you are having.

Comment: Also look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776862/when-should-we-use-instanceof-and-when-not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`instanceof` used to check that given object is of type Class(SomeClass - right side parameter). You cannot use `Class` to check that instanceof another class. To check class equality or assainability you can use `SomeClass.isAssignableFrom(clas)`

Answer (score 1):

[From Java Tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You
>   can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance
>   of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular
>   interface.

Reference variable `clas` is not a type of `SomeClass` or its sub-class.