# Describe the Strategy Design Pattern in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I was reading about `Strategy Design pattern` but not able to understand what is significance of this and how and where it is useful? Can some one explain this design pattern with its significance and where it is useful in programming?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/370270/20654  which may be a good example of the strategy pattern

Comment: another example in java can be found at http://javabyranjith.blogspot.in/2017/04/strategy-design-pattern.html

Answer (score 3):

Consider `java.util.Comparator`. It defines the way two objects are compared. A `TreeSet` created with different implementations of Comparator will sort elements in different ways. Another example from Java SE is `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExcecutionHandler` which determines policy to process tasks rejected by `ThreadPoolExecutor`

Comment: So for any problem, the diffrent solution in our mind is the strategy design patern

Comment: It might be put as a class designed to determine behaviour of another class.