# Is 'Strategy Design Pattern' no more than the basic use of polymorphism?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, interface, polymorphism, strategy-pattern

In **Strategy Design Pattern**, what we do is

- Create a common interface.
- Implement a set of classes using that interface with overridden method(s).
- Let the run time to choose the actual class for an object which has the same type with that common interface and call the overridden method(s) which will resolve correctly according to the class.

My question is, **Isn't it the basic example of polymorphism and method overriding we learn?**

other than the possibility of using an abstract class too, replacing the common interface.

Comment: Perhaps we can say that polymorphism (language feature) facilitates the implementation of Stragy Pattern (programming solution to some common problem). Kind of hammer lets you build a house.

Comment: @Edgars In this case it is more like it only uses the hammer. Isn't it?

Comment: Other design pattern also uses polymorphism. The purpose of polymorhism is to inverse the dependence. Also see state pattern, bridge pattern

Comment: @mubeen Yes indeed. But I am really trying to point out is, it is no more than basic polymorphism.

Comment: @SupunWijerathne: It's not a "basic use of polymorphism". It's a specific use of polymorphism. That's why it is a pattern.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I appreciate if you can elaborate as an answer. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you describe is a way to *implement* the strategy pattern.  You also describe how to implement a whole lot of different designs, since there are many, many reasons why we might want to create a common interface, make different implementations, and select one at runtime for different situations.

There are also other ways to implement the strategy pattern.

But, you know, a design is not code.  A design is a mental model of how the software works -- a human thing, not bits.  A design pattern is a common way of composing solutions to common sorts of problems.  Again it happens in your head and not in bits.

The strategy pattern in particular is about making objects with *interchangeable algorithms*, any of which could be used for a particular purpose.

So, yes, you define an interface... but it's not the interface to a data object -- it doesn't have getters and setters and state mutators, etc.  The interface defines how the object interacts with the algorithm that is used for a particular purpose.  A chess game might use a "Player" strategy, for example, with a method called "SelectNextMove".

And, yes you make implementations of that interface, but the implementations aren't "things" that become "parts" of the containing object, they are different algorithms that could be used to perform whatever function the object requires.  A chess game could support many different strategies that could be used to select the next move for the computer player.

So when you're thinking about the design of a chess game, for example, in your head, you will probably find it useful to think about strategy for choosing the next move separately from the objects that model the board and ensure that the selected move is recorded, communicated, and rendered properly.  The strategy for choosing the next move is independent of these things.

If you're a good software designer, you will code it independently too, so that the separation of concerns in code will mirror the separation of concerns in your head, make it easy for people maintaining the code to think about it in the most useful way, and allow new strategies for choosing the next move to be swapped in and out whenever you want.

Comment: @Matt Thanx for the great explanation. And could you please also elaborate what you point out by ''a way to implement the strategy pattern'' ? Could you please show/cite some other ways?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne, Sure.  The most common way to specify a strategy is as an implementation of a specific interface, but you could use a pointer to  a function, the name of a library to load, a snippet of code that gets executed dynamically, an enum constant that selects an algorithm or behaviour, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Strategy implementation can be even simpler in dynamic languages such Javascript. Whenever you pass a callback arround, your are probably extending a Strategy implementation.

### Example: sorting arrays

Javascript's native arrays have a method called `sort` that will return a brand new sorted array. It can have one parameter, the `comparisonFunction`, a callback that will compare 2 items in the array and return:

- `1` if the first element is to be considered **higher than** the second.
- `0` if it is to be considered **equal**
- `-1` if it is to be considered **lower then**

So, you can use whatever strategy you want to sort the array:

```
[5, 2, 4, 1, 3].sort(); // default: sort in the natural order

[5, 2, 4, 1, 3].sort(function reverse(first, second){
    if (first > second) return -1;
    if (first == second) return 0;
    if (first < second) return 1;
});

[5, 2, 4, 1, 3].sort(function random(first, second){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) - 1;
});
```

When you are creating your on libraries and expect a callback that will do some work on your data, you are probably implementing the Strategy pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism is one of the three key pillars of Object Oriented Programming:

- [Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))

  > In programming languages and type theory, polymorphism [...] is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types.
- [Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(software_engineering))

  > [A]bstraction is a technique for managing complexity of computer systems. It works by establishing a level of complexity on which a person interacts with the system, suppressing the more complex details below the current level. The programmer works with an idealized interface (usually well defined) and can add additional levels of functionality that would otherwise be too complex to handle.
- [Inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_(object-oriented_programming))

  > In object-oriented programming, inheritance is when an object or class is based on another object (prototypal inheritance) or class (class-based inheritance), using the same implementation (inheriting from an object or class) specifying implementation to maintain the same behavior (realizing an interface; inheriting behavior). It is a mechanism for code reuse and to allow independent extensions of the original software via public classes and interfaces.

Being such a key pillar of OOP, to say there the same thing is akin to saying racing is the same thing as driving (driving being the "core underlying thing" that you're doing). This is also like saying the [Facade Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) is simply Abstraction.

Much like racing is driving *fast and competitively*, the [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) is Polymorphism *used at runtime to select an algorithm's behavior*. It is an application and implementation of Polymorphism, absolutely, but it's really a *specific* application and implementation of Polymorphism.

Comment: Thanx for your answer. Point taken -> In a nutshell what all we do in design patterns is utilizing basic oop principles. 
But in different with the latter part of your answer,  I don't see myself "Facade is simply abstraction". Can you please elaborate why you concerned in that way?

Comment: A Facade is primarily just an implementation of Abstraction, in much the same way that Strategy is centered around Polymorphism. That's what I meant by that.

Answer (score 1):

Polymorphism: there is an interface or base class where concrete implementations can be exchanged.

Strategy Pattern: A *part of a logic* is put into a separate class accessed by an interface in order to exchange it. It's therefore using polymorphism in a specific way.

Many OO patterns are using polymorphism. And most of them are kind of basic. Let's take the [composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), which I always refer to as the one which shows the power of polymorphism best.

Answer (score 1):

[Strategy_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) uses run-time polymorphism to make algorithms interchangeable within that family.

Replacing one algorithm with-in family of multiple algorithms is one part of Strategy pattern. Strategy pattern can use Context also.

You can achieve replacement of algorithm at run time without using interface/run-time polymorphism.

*Call a method in Context by passing a condition. Have switch case statements calling different methods based on individual case*. This approach is not as clean as run-time polymorphism but still you can achieve it.

Strategy UML:

[image]

Related posts:

[Confused about strategy design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757559/confused-about-strategy-design-pattern/34758462#34758462)

Answer (score 0):

Strategy can be used as an example of Polymorphism in some manners. But it's not a good start for OOP newbies as it's more complex than other patterns.

Yes you can replace interface with abstract class and even normal class. It doesn't matter. "Abstraction" in OOP is not all classes must be derivative of an abstract class or interface.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that when using polymorphism you must typically destroy the object and replace it with a new instance. It could be expensive to constantly create/destroy the new instance. The strategy pattern is one way you can implement lazy loading/storing previously created instances for later.

Here is an example in Swift.

```
protocol Strategy {

}

class CheapStrategy: Strategy {
    // cheap to create this
}

class ExpensiveStrategy: Strategy {
    // expensive to create this
}

// Polymorphism
// Alternating between different strategies.
// The previous value of s is always created and destroyed.

var s: Strategy!
s = CheapStrategy()
s = ExpensiveStrategy()
s = CheapStrategy()
s = ExpensiveStrategy()


// Strategy Pattern

class Context {
    lazy var cheapStrategy = CheapStrategy()
    lazy var expensiveStrategy = ExpensiveStrategy()
    var s: Strategy!
}

// Alternate between different strategies using previously allocated.

let c = Context()
c.s = c.cheapStrategy
c.s = c.expensiveStrategy
c.s = c.cheapStrategy
c.s = c.expensiveStrategy
```

Comment: could you please elaborate. Your idea is too generic to understand clearly. Thank You.