# Confusion regarding inheritance based on examples

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, aggregation

Sometimes I get often confused between when to derive class(use inheritance) and when not to.So for instance I have a code like this :

```
public class Payroll
{
    public void ProcessPayroll(Employee e) //abstraction
    {
         e.ProcessPayroll();
    }
}

Class Employee : Payroll
{
    public virtual void ProcessPayroll()
    {
       //Process Payroll
    }
}

class FulltimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public override void ProcessPayroll()
    {
       //Payroll processing based on fulltime employee
    }
}
```

This make sense :

```
class FulltimeEmployee : Employee
```

Becuase `FulltimeEmployee is a Employee` so `IS-A relationship` holds true here.

But I am confused here for below relationship so as to does this inheritance make sense as it is not an `"IS-A" relationship` ?

```
Class Employee : Payroll
```

Also Inheritance always have to follow IS-A relationship ?

**Another Example :**

> Requirement says "Employee cannot exist without Company"

Based on this I did this :

```
public class Company

public class Employee : Company
```

Now does this make sense ?

**Update :**

I think above can be better represented using `Aggregation` :

```
public class Company
{ 
    Employee E; //because Company has-a Employee
}
```

But tomorrow if requirement says **Company can exist without Employee too** that means I have to come to this class and update the code.

Isnt this will violate `Open and Closed principle` ?

Comment: An employee is not a payroll. There should be no inheritance relationship there. An employee might be *on* a payroll, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Is an `Employee` a special type of `Payroll`? It doesn't sound like this is the case.

Comment: inheritance is an "IS-A" relationship. Class (implementation) inheritance is a special case - there are also interfaces in Java which may be better suited. "Employee is a company" or "Employee is a payroll" don't make sense.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes you are right but Employee is a part of payroll process.So I am trying to understand whether Is-A relationship is compulsory for inheritance or not

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow By using inheritance you are representing `Employee` as a specialised type of `Payroll`, and indeed of `Company` in your other example.

Comment: @John Employee and Payroll are 2 seperate process and Employee is a part of payroll process.Actually this is what I am trying to understand and figure out whether Is-A relationship should always holds true for inheritance

Comment: @AndyTurner I have updated question with 1 more doubt.Can you please shed some lights on it

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I have updated question with 1 more doubt.Can you please shed some lights on it

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow Employee(s) should be a list, unless you expect the Company you represent to only ever have one employee. The open / closed principle says your class should be open for _extension_ and closed for _modification_. I don't see how that violates it.

Answer (score 3):

Requirement says "Employee cannot exist without Company" it means company has a employees. 
Has-A relationship is also known as composition.
You don't require this Class Employee : Payroll. It should be just class Employee.

In Payroll class, Employee object is injected, so it can process on instant methods.
Also for  good practice follow this [Prefer composition over inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance)

Answer for updated part:
Open close principal says "Class is open for extension but closed for modification"

```
public class Company
    {
        private readonly IEmployee e;
        public Company(IEmployee e)
        {
            this.e = e;
        }
    }
    public interface IEmployee
    { //Some employee related methods
    }
```

Here you have injected IEmployee in Company class. Now you can extend Company class functionality using instant of IEmployee. 
Look at Strategy Pattern example, which hopefully clarified your doubt [Real World Example of the Strategy Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370258/real-world-example-of-the-strategy-pattern)

Comment: Tomorrow if requirements say that Company can exist without employees than how to handle this requirement in your code?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow: In that case, just remove Employee from company class where you are injecting.

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking is rather HAS-A relationship, so you need composition:

```
public class Employee
{
  Payroll payroll;
  Company company;
  ...
}
```

As every employee is hired somewhere, so it has a company he works at.

On the other side, company has employees, so it could be designed as well as:

```
public class Company
{
  List<Employee> employees;
  ...
}
```

You need to prepare yoursef also for situation where `Employee` has no `Company` or vice versa, then respective fields in classes would be `null`, Considering that, you need to write your methods with `null` checks to handle such situation, like:

```
if(employees == null || employeses.Count == 0)
  Console.WriteLine("Sorry, company has no employees!");
```

Comment: But tomorrow if requirement says Company can exist without Employee too than I have to come to Company class and update the code.Isnt this violating Open/Closed principle?

Comment: @ILoveStackoverflow Then company should have `employees = null` and in functions using `employees` you should handle case, when this field is `null`. With such design, it would be closed for modification.

Comment: Can you show me in the code,How to handle both the requirement properly without violating Open/Closed principle please.