# Implementation Strategy Pattern based on Other Strategy

Tags: strategy-pattern

I am trying to design an application which has have two work features,
1. Job Work
2. Incident Work.

Further more, Job work is divided in 5 different processor (JobWork1 to JobWork5) based on Job Type and Incident Work is divided into 7 different processor (IncidentWork 1 to IncidentWork7) based on Incident type.

Please help me to understand how can I combine two strategy here.

Comment: If you implement one strategy for JOB, it's easy to implement for other : IncidentWork. Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370258/real-world-example-of-the-strategy-pattern/35180265#35180265.  When you load one strategy, the concrete strategy of Job can load IncidentWork strategy

Comment: Hello @Ravindrababu, Thanks. I have implemented strategy by strategy and then stitched them together. It works!